# How universal are the Windows Ctrl shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I would like to know if:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> *copy*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> *paste*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> *cut*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> *bold*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> *print*
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> *undo*

keyboard shortcuts work on all Windows versions above '98, all Non-English Windows and on all keyboards (English, German, Chinese...)?

How universal are the Ctrl shortcuts?

Comment: I would say yes. In german Windows versions ctrl+c+v+x+p+z is working. Im not sure about ctrl+b

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful but I need to be 100% sure that the answer is YES for all three cases :)

Comment: Those are all universal. Of course they can also be changed by software also.  We can't give you a 100% answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that it can depend from program to program... but my question is related to default behavior of these shortcuts.

Comment: So you want someone to test multiple keyboards in multiple different language editions of all Windows versions since 98?  Probably not going to happen...  Which ones have you tried already?

Comment: Haha :) I know that's impossible. You know what I meant with "100% sure" -> very high probability. I just thought that there are developers who already researched on this problem. Also, there is much easier way then testing on keyboards - read Microsoft documentation :) (for example chinese: http://windows.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7). Anyway, I think I've got the answer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very universal.  Even among the same computer, different programs may treat these keys in different ways.

They are just recommended to be used this way, but each program is free to decide what its keys will do.